# Having label and caption optional for custom tabularray environment

Tags: xparse, tabularray

This is a followup question to a [similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701854/expand-conditional-in-the-outer-specification-for-a-tabularray-table):

I like to create a table environment and to have the option creating a label/caption.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTblrTheme{exc-main}{
  \SetTblrStyle{head}{%
    bg=blue!10,
    fg=blue
  }
  \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt,hspan=minimal}
  \SetTblrInner{%
    row{odd} = {bg=black!10},
    row{1}={%
      bg=blue!10,
      fg=blue,
      font=\bfseries,
      halign={c},
      valign={m},
    },
    width = \linewidth,
    hline{1,Z} = {2pt,fg=red}, % toprule and bottomrule
    hline{2} = {1pt,fg=red}, % midrule
    }
  }

  \NewDocumentEnvironment{excTableEnv}{ o m o }{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{\SetTblrOuter{#1}}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{\SetTblrInner{#3}}%
  \begin{tblr}[%
    theme=exc-main,
      entry=none,
      label=none,
      long,
      ]{%
        colspec ={#2},
        row{2-Z}={font=\sffamily},
        rowhead = 1, %<- first row is head
      }
    }
    {\end{tblr}}

  \begin{document}
  \chapter{test}
\begin{excTableEnv}{XX}
  Top & Top \\
  tba & tba \\
\end{excTableEnv}

  \ref{tab:1}
\begin{excTableEnv}[label={tab:1},caption={something}]{XX}
  Head &  Head \\
  tba & tba \\
\end{excTableEnv}

\begin{excTableEnv}{XX}
  Top & Top \\
  tba & tba \\
\end{excTableEnv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works fine for the environment without any optional argument. But `label={tab:1}` is not considered or does not overwrite the default setting.

Comment: Try to remove `label=none`...

Comment: Then it works, but as default I do not want to have the table labelled or have a number for it. Just occsionnally there should be a caption, label, number to  it.

Comment: Remove `label=none` and use `\IfValueTF{#1}{\SetTblrOuter{label=none,#1}}{\SetTblrOuter{label=none}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local keys take precedence over keys provided by `\SetTblrOuter`.

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTblrTheme{exc-main}{
  \SetTblrStyle{head}{%
    bg=blue!10,
    fg=blue
  }
  \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt,hspan=minimal}
  \SetTblrInner{%
    row{odd} = {bg=black!10},
    row{1}={%
      bg=blue!10,
      fg=blue,
      font=\bfseries,
      halign={c},
      valign={m},
    },
    width = \linewidth,
    hline{1,Z} = {2pt,fg=red}, % toprule and bottomrule
    hline{2} = {1pt,fg=red}, % midrule
  }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{excTableEnv}{o m o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\SetTblrOuter{label=none,#1}}{\SetTblrOuter{label=none}}%
  %\IfValueT{#1}{\SetTblrOuter{#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\SetTblrInner{#3}}%
  \begin{tblr}[%
      theme=exc-main,
      entry=none,
      %label=none,
      long,
    ]{%
      colspec ={#2},
      row{2-Z}={font=\sffamily},
      rowhead = 1, %<- first row is head
    }
  }{
  \end{tblr}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

\begin{excTableEnv}{XX}
  Top & Top \\
  tba & tba \\
\end{excTableEnv}

\ref{tab:1}

\begin{excTableEnv}[caption={something},label={tab:1}]{XX}
  Head &  Head \\
  tba & tba \\
\end{excTableEnv}

\begin{excTableEnv}{XX}
  Top & Top \\
  tba & tba \\
\end{excTableEnv}
\end{document}
```